# Weird behavior when resizing SKView - nodes randomly scale

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa7DN.jpg)

The "handle" in the middle resizes the left view and the right view. Here is my storyboard:

[image: Storyboard]

Here I present the scene:

```swift
if let leftScene = LeftScene(fileNamed: "LeftScene") {
    self.skView.presentScene(leftScene)
}
```

Here is my .sks file:

[image: Scene]

I want the sprite in the middle to keep its size when the view resizes, so I can't use the `aspectFill` scale mode, because that would shrink/expand it.

Comment: Ok,  the content is not resizing fast enough it looks like.  On redraw,  make sure you call setNeedsDisplay()

Comment: The black bars are still there. Here is what they look like: https://imgur.com/a/3lwSvuO. Maybe I should note that the `SKView` isn't the main view of the view controller, it's a child of it.

Comment: OK, so center is not what you want, because center keeps the proportions the same.  Try left on your left window, and right on your right window.  Also, delete the useless comments when you can.

Comment: what if you mounted it to the right

Comment: Then the black bars only show on the left

Comment: When on the left.. it only shows on the right when expanding.  When on the right, it only shows on the left when expanding?

Comment: Yup, exactly like that

Comment: Yeah,  that means the content window underneath the view is not resizing fast enough. From what I am reading,  it should be `.redraw`. https://useyourloaf.com/blog/stretching-redrawing-and-positioning-with-contentmode/

Comment: `.redraw` has the bug in the original question. Maybe it's because the skView is a child of the view controller's view? I don't know, I set the content mode on both and .redraw isn't working properly

Comment: I wonder if you can set the view `isAsynchronous = false` when resizing and then `isAsynchronous=true` when not to get it to not draw black bars

Comment: Still doesn't work :( thank you for your time. Maybe it helps to add that when expanding quickly the green part (the left view) it "overflows" under the handle?

Comment: Another interesting thing I found is that if I remove the animation of the constraint (when dragging) the black part gets small, almost gone. If I increase the animation duration, the black bar appears huge as I drag, then it animates until it disappears. I can't get rid of the animation because it looks jagged otherwise. And even if I remove it, a tiny black bar still shows.

Comment: It updates the view's size before animating the constraint

Comment: Ok, so it is resizing to the final view size prior to animation, makes sense.  Can you fake this?  Turn the scene into an image and overlay it with a UIImageView?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Take your scene,  convert it to an image (skview can do this) then place a uiimageview on top of your scene so that they are seeing the image and not an skview.

Comment: You mean generate an image from the scene and place it in an UIImageView?

Comment: Yes,  creating an illusion

Comment: What should I do after this?